# TikZ: scale and shift SVG path

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg

I drew a curve in an external program and exported it to an SVG path (I used Python's matplotlib, it would have been difficult to draw using TikZ).

Now I would like to integrate this path in a TikZ image, to add annotations etc. For that purpose, I would like to rescale and shift the path into my TikZ coordinate system. To make that task a little easier, I also drew a "bounding box" into the SVG graphic, so I have two SVG paths now in the same coordinate system.

Using the size of the "bounding box", it becomes easy to scale the SVG paths to the desired size, but any attempt to shift the scope containing the paths seems to fail: using `xshift` or `yshift` has seemingly no effect.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% my coordinate system, align the paths onto this grid
\draw[help lines] (0, 0) grid (20, 10);

% scaling factors obtained from bounding box, adding an xshift appears to have no effect
\begin{scope}[xscale={20cm/710.18182}, yscale={10cm/453.6}]
% the "bounding box" (comment out later)
\draw[color=red] svg "m 161.50909,100.44 v 453.6 h 710.18182";
% the curve
\draw[thick] svg "m 161.50909,347.85818 3.56875,-1.19585 3.56876,-3.42262 3.56875,-5.40197 3.56875,-7.13389 3.56875,-8.61839 3.56876,-9.8555 3.56875,-10.84516 3.56875,-11.58742 7.13751,-24.41193 7.1375,-24.41192 3.56876,-11.58742 3.56875,-10.84517 3.56875,-9.85549 3.56876,-8.6184 3.56875,-7.13389 3.56875,-5.40196 3.56875,-3.42262 3.56876,-1.19585 3.56875,1.16149 3.56875,3.18207 3.56876,4.74905 3.56875,5.86244 10.70626,19.7316 3.56875,5.77996 3.56875,4.62535 3.56876,3.01713 3.56875,1.12025 3.56875,-0.40549 3.56876,-1.39516 7.1375,-3.61506 3.56875,-1.14774 3.56876,0.007 3.56875,1.69756 3.56875,3.92433 3.56875,6.68716 3.56876,9.8177 3.56875,12.64238 3.56875,14.99285 3.56876,16.86911 3.56875,18.27115 7.1375,38.85152 7.13751,38.76906 3.56875,18.16805 3.56876,16.77878 3.56875,15.1853 3.56875,13.44158 3.56875,11.54765 3.56876,9.50351 3.56875,7.30915 3.56875,4.96456 3.56876,2.46976 3.56875,-0.17525 3.56875,-2.97049 3.56875,-5.70682 3.56876,-7.54773 3.56875,-8.28409 3.56875,-7.91591 3.56876,-6.65182 3.56875,-5.32636 3.56875,-4.14818 3.56875,-3.11727 3.56876,-2.23364 3.56875,-1.49727 3.56875,-0.90818 3.56876,-0.46637 3.56875,-0.17182 17.84376,-0.0245 96.35633,-0.0272 3.56875,-0.19006 3.56876,-0.51588 3.56875,-0.97067 3.56875,-1.41867 3.56876,-1.82594 3.56875,-2.19248 3.56875,-2.5183 3.56875,-2.8034 3.56876,-3.04775 3.56875,-3.2514 7.1375,-6.95079 17.84377,-18.08969 3.56875,-3.41431 3.56875,-3.25139 3.56876,-3.04776 3.56875,-2.80339 3.56875,-2.5183 3.56876,-2.19249 3.56875,-1.82594 3.56875,-1.41867 3.56875,-0.97066 3.56876,-0.51588 3.56875,-0.19006 17.84376,-0.0272 h 217.69393 v 0";
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness's sake, I'll answer my own question, @Skillmon provided the clue I was looking for. Adding a coordinate point, such as `(0,0)` to the `\draw` command of an SVG path makes it accept the `xshift` and `yshift` instructions in the `scope`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% my coordinate system, align the paths onto this grid
\draw[help lines] (0, 0) grid (20, 10);

% scaling factors and shift values obtained from bounding box
\begin{scope}[xscale={20cm/710.18182}, yscale={10cm/453.6}, 
              xshift=-161.50909, yshift=-100.44]
% the "bounding box" (comment out later)
\draw[color=red] (0,0) svg "m 161.50909,100.44 v 453.6 h 710.18182";
% the curve
\draw[thick] (0,0) svg "m 161.50909,347.85818 3.56875,-1.19585 3.56876,-3.42262 3.56875,-5.40197 3.56875,-7.13389 3.56875,-8.61839 3.56876,-9.8555 3.56875,-10.84516 3.56875,-11.58742 7.13751,-24.41193 7.1375,-24.41192 3.56876,-11.58742 3.56875,-10.84517 3.56875,-9.85549 3.56876,-8.6184 3.56875,-7.13389 3.56875,-5.40196 3.56875,-3.42262 3.56876,-1.19585 3.56875,1.16149 3.56875,3.18207 3.56876,4.74905 3.56875,5.86244 10.70626,19.7316 3.56875,5.77996 3.56875,4.62535 3.56876,3.01713 3.56875,1.12025 3.56875,-0.40549 3.56876,-1.39516 7.1375,-3.61506 3.56875,-1.14774 3.56876,0.007 3.56875,1.69756 3.56875,3.92433 3.56875,6.68716 3.56876,9.8177 3.56875,12.64238 3.56875,14.99285 3.56876,16.86911 3.56875,18.27115 7.1375,38.85152 7.13751,38.76906 3.56875,18.16805 3.56876,16.77878 3.56875,15.1853 3.56875,13.44158 3.56875,11.54765 3.56876,9.50351 3.56875,7.30915 3.56875,4.96456 3.56876,2.46976 3.56875,-0.17525 3.56875,-2.97049 3.56875,-5.70682 3.56876,-7.54773 3.56875,-8.28409 3.56875,-7.91591 3.56876,-6.65182 3.56875,-5.32636 3.56875,-4.14818 3.56875,-3.11727 3.56876,-2.23364 3.56875,-1.49727 3.56875,-0.90818 3.56876,-0.46637 3.56875,-0.17182 17.84376,-0.0245 96.35633,-0.0272 3.56875,-0.19006 3.56876,-0.51588 3.56875,-0.97067 3.56875,-1.41867 3.56876,-1.82594 3.56875,-2.19248 3.56875,-2.5183 3.56875,-2.8034 3.56876,-3.04775 3.56875,-3.2514 7.1375,-6.95079 17.84377,-18.08969 3.56875,-3.41431 3.56875,-3.25139 3.56876,-3.04776 3.56875,-2.80339 3.56875,-2.5183 3.56876,-2.19249 3.56875,-1.82594 3.56875,-1.41867 3.56875,-0.97066 3.56876,-0.51588 3.56875,-0.19006 17.84376,-0.0272 h 217.69393 v 0";
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: solution 1]
Why go through this process? Now that the curve is correctly placed into the TikZ coordinate system, additional information can be added to the curve in the right location, for example the control points for this spline curve. For example, for a slightly modified curve:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% my coordinate system, align the paths onto this grid
\draw[help lines] (0, 0) grid (15, 10);

% scaling factors and shift values obtained from bounding box, curve is flipped upside down using negative y-scale
\begin{scope}[xscale={15cm/710.18182}, yscale={-10cm/453.6}, 
              xshift=-161.50909, yshift={-453.6-100.44}]
% the "bounding box" (comment out later)
\draw[color=red] (0,0) svg "m 161.50909,100.44 v 453.6 h 710.18182";
% the curve
\draw[thick] (0,0) svg "m 161.50909,347.85818 4.73455,-1.19585 4.73454,-3.42262 4.73455,-5.40197 4.73454,-7.13389 4.73455,-8.61839 4.73454,-9.8555 4.73455,-10.84516 4.73454,-11.58742 9.46909,-24.41193 9.4691,-24.41192 4.73454,-11.58742 4.73455,-10.84517 4.73454,-9.85549 4.73455,-8.6184 4.73454,-7.13389 4.73455,-5.40196 4.73454,-3.42262 4.73455,-1.19585 4.73455,1.16149 4.73454,3.18207 4.73455,4.74905 4.73454,5.86244 4.73455,6.52222 4.73454,6.7284 4.73455,6.48098 4.73454,5.77996 4.73455,4.62535 4.73454,3.01713 4.73455,1.12025 4.73454,-0.40549 4.73455,-1.39516 9.46909,-3.61506 4.73455,-1.14774 4.73454,0.007 4.73455,1.69756 4.73454,3.92433 4.73455,6.68716 4.73454,9.81701 4.73455,12.63757 4.73454,14.9798 4.73455,16.84368 4.73455,18.22922 9.46909,38.7017 4.73454,19.5158 4.73455,18.98797 4.73454,17.9818 4.73455,16.55777 4.73454,14.95781 4.73455,13.24237 4.73455,11.41148 4.73454,9.46512 4.73455,7.4033 4.73454,5.22602 4.73455,2.93328 4.73454,0.52508 4.73455,-1.99859 4.73454,-4.48652 4.73455,-6.33391 4.73455,-7.38955 4.73454,-7.65347 4.73454,-7.12564 4.73455,-5.96003 4.73455,-4.77243 4.73454,-3.71677 4.73455,-2.79307 4.73454,-2.00134 4.73455,-1.34156 4.73454,-0.81373 4.73455,-0.41786 4.73454,-0.15395 28.40728,-0.022 75.75272,-0.0272 4.73455,-0.19006 4.73455,-0.51588 4.73454,-0.97067 4.73455,-1.41867 4.73454,-1.82594 4.73455,-2.19248 4.73454,-2.5183 4.73455,-2.8034 4.73454,-3.04775 4.73455,-3.2514 9.46909,-6.95079 23.67273,-18.08969 4.73454,-3.41431 4.73455,-3.25139 4.73454,-3.04776 4.73455,-2.80339 4.73455,-2.5183 4.73454,-2.19249 4.73454,-1.82594 4.73455,-1.41867 4.73455,-0.97066 4.73454,-0.51588 4.73455,-0.19006 23.67272,-0.0272 h 99.42546 v 0";
\end{scope}
% draw control points with known coordinates
\foreach \i/\x/\y in {1/0.0/4.545, 2/1.0/4.545, 3/2.0/6.364, 4/3.0/9.091, 5/4.0/6.364, 
                      6/5.0/8.182, 7/6.0/2.727, 8/6.5/0.909, 9/7.5/2.727, 10/9.5/2.727, 
                      11/9.8/2.727, 12/12.2/2.727, 13/12.5/4.182, 14/15.0/4.182}{
\fill[color=blue!70!black] (\x,\y) circle [radius=1mm] node[below=1ex] (c-\i) {$c_{\i}$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: solution 2 with control points]

Answer (score 1):

You can shift the `svg` path simply by changing the first coordinate pair after your `m` to `0,0` and putting a Ti*k*Z coordinate in front of `svg`, like in the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% my coordinate system, align the paths onto this grid
\draw[help lines] (0, 0) grid (20, 10);

% scaling factors obtained from bounding box, adding an xshift appears to have no effect
\begin{scope}[xscale={20cm/710.18182}, yscale={10cm/453.6}]
% the "bounding box" (comment out later)
\draw[color=red] svg "m 161.50909,100.44 v 453.6 h 710.18182";
% the curve
\draw[thick] (0,6) svg { m 0,0 3.56875,-1.19585 3.56876,-3.42262 3.56875,-5.40197 3.56875,-7.13389 3.56875,-8.61839 3.56876,-9.8555 3.56875,-10.84516 3.56875,-11.58742 7.13751,-24.41193 7.1375,-24.41192 3.56876,-11.58742 3.56875,-10.84517 3.56875,-9.85549 3.56876,-8.6184 3.56875,-7.13389 3.56875,-5.40196 3.56875,-3.42262 3.56876,-1.19585 3.56875,1.16149 3.56875,3.18207 3.56876,4.74905 3.56875,5.86244 10.70626,19.7316 3.56875,5.77996 3.56875,4.62535 3.56876,3.01713 3.56875,1.12025 3.56875,-0.40549 3.56876,-1.39516 7.1375,-3.61506 3.56875,-1.14774 3.56876,0.007 3.56875,1.69756 3.56875,3.92433 3.56875,6.68716 3.56876,9.8177 3.56875,12.64238 3.56875,14.99285 3.56876,16.86911 3.56875,18.27115 7.1375,38.85152 7.13751,38.76906 3.56875,18.16805 3.56876,16.77878 3.56875,15.1853 3.56875,13.44158 3.56875,11.54765 3.56876,9.50351 3.56875,7.30915 3.56875,4.96456 3.56876,2.46976 3.56875,-0.17525 3.56875,-2.97049 3.56875,-5.70682 3.56876,-7.54773 3.56875,-8.28409 3.56875,-7.91591 3.56876,-6.65182 3.56875,-5.32636 3.56875,-4.14818 3.56875,-3.11727 3.56876,-2.23364 3.56875,-1.49727 3.56875,-0.90818 3.56876,-0.46637 3.56875,-0.17182 17.84376,-0.0245 96.35633,-0.0272 3.56875,-0.19006 3.56876,-0.51588 3.56875,-0.97067 3.56875,-1.41867 3.56876,-1.82594 3.56875,-2.19248 3.56875,-2.5183 3.56875,-2.8034 3.56876,-3.04775 3.56875,-3.2514 7.1375,-6.95079 17.84377,-18.08969 3.56875,-3.41431 3.56875,-3.25139 3.56876,-3.04776 3.56875,-2.80339 3.56875,-2.5183 3.56876,-2.19249 3.56875,-1.82594 3.56875,-1.41867 3.56875,-0.97066 3.56876,-0.51588 3.56875,-0.19006 17.84376,-0.0272 h 217.69393 v 0 };
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you need to use the `xshift` mechanism you can also do so after you set a Ti*k*Z coordinate in front of your `svg` path (the first coordinate after your `m` will be a relative movement from the Ti*k*Z coordinate in pt, so if you use `m 0,0` you'll start at the spot your Ti*k*Z coordinate is at, but any other coordinate will work as well, you'll just have to adapt your `xshift`/`yshift` to that, so you can also use this with `m 161.50909,347.85818` -- the `xshift`/`yshift` will affect the Ti*k*Z coordinate which will be the starting point of your `svg` path).

Comment: Your solution does not quite create the desired result, but it pointed me in the right direction. The curve is too low (you used an arbitrary coordinate of `(0,6)`) and I wanted to avoid modifying the svg path, so that I would be able to use shift commands or similar in other parts of the document. 
Having said that, just adding the `(0,0)` in front of the paths makes them use the xshift and yshift values, and now `[xscale={20cm/710.18182}, yscale={10cm/453.6}, xshift=-161.50909, yshift=-100.44]` works!

Comment: If you edit your solution, changing the SVG paths back but adding the `(0.0)` and adding the xshift and yshift values to the scope, I will accept it. Thanks, that is really helpful.

Comment: @japamat of course i used an arbitrary coordinate, you never specified a coordinate...

Comment: Sorry if I did not make this entirely clear, but the transformation was supposed to perfectly align the "bounding box", for which I know the true coordinates, with the outline of the TikZ grid. Based on the SVG coordinates of the bounding box, what is needed is `xshift=-161.50909, yshift=-100.44`. This transformation did not work before, but the addition of the `(0,0)` changed that.